# Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created a topic and i put a simple-producer to publish some message in that topic

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic streams-file-input

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --streams-file-input
```

I am running the below simple example in kafka streams and i got a weird exception which i cannot handle

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.3:9092");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

            // setting offset reset to earliest so that we can re-run the demo code with the same pre-loaded data
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

            KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

            builder.stream("streams-file-input").to("streams-pipe-output");

            KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
            streams.start();

            // usually the stream application would be running forever,
            // in this example we just let it run for some time and stop since the input data is finite.
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

            streams.close();
```

```
 Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:299)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:218)
        Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while creating the state manager
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:71)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:86)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:550)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:577)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$000(StreamThread.java:68)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:123)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:222)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:232)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$1.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:227)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$2.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:182)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:436)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$SyncGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:679)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:658)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:426)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:278)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:243)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.ensurePartitionAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:345)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:977)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:937)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:295)
            ... 1 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\kafka-streams\my-streapplication\0_0\.lock (The system cannot find the path specified)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
            at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.lockStateDirectory(ProcessorStateManager.java:125)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:93)
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:69)
```

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Whatever i did i got this exception. I am running kafka cluster in vmware with Ubuntu(the version i use is **kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0**) Maybe the problem is the ram-Cpu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\kafka-streams\my-streapplication\0_0\.lock (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

it means that the parent directory `C:\tmp\kafka-streams` for your application state does not exsist. It is a default directory in `StreamConfig`. I don't know why it's created failed on Windows.

You can set `StreamConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG` as a specified directory.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Muyoo this is the correct fix:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"my-stremapplication");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.210:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
```