# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.cluster.Broker.endPoints()Lscala/collection/Map with updated kafka version 0.10.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on embedded kafka tests. ANd I was having an issue with rebalance with kafka 0.10.1.1
similar to this [Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994217/exception-in-thread-streamthread-1-org-apache-kafka-streams-errors-streamsexce)

According to suggestions I found online, I updated the kafka version to 0.10.2.0.
However now the tests throw this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.cluster.Broker.endPoints()Lscala/collection/Map;
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.brokersToEndpoints(KafkaStore.java:277)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.<init>(KafkaStore.java:122)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:144)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:37)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:149)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.RestApp.start(RestApp.java:59)
    at com.kafka.EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.start(EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.java:82)
    at com.kafka.EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.before(EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.java:100)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at com.CustomizedIntegrationTestClassRunner.run(CustomizedIntegrationTestClassRunner.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Are there any changes I need to make in the config properties ?